# group by ID and filter by condition - if something then mark them as something else

Tags: mysql, group-by, min, group-concat

On my query right now I'm receiving and ID  that can be repeated and the status, so I want to group by ID but if **any** of the rows has status ACTIVE then it should appear ACTIVE.

I have something like this:

[image]

And I want to end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Where does mark as 1 else 0 come into it?

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, I change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is aggregate function `MIN()` which will return `ACTIVE` when both values are present for an `id`, because is considered less than `CANCELLED`:

```
SELECT id, MIN(status) status
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id;
```

A more general solution, that does not depend on the comparison of these particular strings would be with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         GROUP_CONCAT(status ORDER BY status = 'ACTIVE' DESC),
         ',', 
         1
       ) status
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1a78aba02c884b7aacad0c0eddcdb21).